# Hide same value in next line for the current column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

From my SQL query, I get this output:

| city | Street | housenumber | flatnumber | inhabitans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACity | AStreet | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| ACity | AStreet | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| ACity | AStreet | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| ACity | AStreet | 1 | SUMFLAT | 8 |
| ACity | AStreet | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| ACity | AStreet | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| ACity | AStreet | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| ACity | AStreet | 2 | SUMFLAT | 8 |
| ACity | AStreet | SUMHOUSE |  | 16 |
| ACity | BStreet | ... |  |  |

What I want is to remove the double entry in each row, so that it looks like this:

| city | Street | housenumber | flatnumber | inhabitans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACity | AStreet | 1 | 1 | 2 |
|  |  |  | 2 | 1 |
|  |  |  | 3 | 5 |
|  |  |  | SUMFLAT | 8 |
|  |  | 2 | 1 | 2 |
|  |  |  | 2 | 1 |
|  |  |  | 3 | 5 |
|  |  |  | SUMFLAT | 8 |
|  |  | SUMHOUSE |  | 16 |
|  | BStreet | ... |  |  |

This is my current code:

```sql
SELECT 
    city, Street, housenumber, flatnumber, inhabitans
FROM   
    db

UNION

SELECT 
    city, Street, housenumber, 'SUMFLAT', SUM(inhabitans)
FROM 
    db
GROUP BY 
    city, street, housenumber

UNION

SELECT 
    city, Street, 'SUMHOUSE', '', SUM(inhabitans)
FROM
    db
GROUP BY 
    city, street
ORDER BY 
    city, Street, housenumber, flatnumber;
```

My questions are:

- is this possible (without changing the order of the lines of the result table)
- if possible in SQL : how?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You could use 2 tables if your concern is storage space.

Comment: You can use `lag` in a wrapping select.

Comment: Do this on the client side.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY .. WITH ROLLUP` instead of UNION.

Comment: useful [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6315/group-by-in-sql-server-with-cube-rollup-and-grouping-sets-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use that many unions in the query, instead
simply get all data from database in to your page and using loop and conditions you can hide duplicate data also you can use html table rowspan for the same.